# How to wait for the async image to load, before adding it to the FixedDocument to print?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, asynchronous

Here's the code:

```
MyView myView = new MyView();
MyView.DataContext = datacontext;

FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
fixedPage.Children.Add(myView);

PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);

FixedDocument fixedDocument = new FixedDocument();
fixedDocument.Pages.Add(pageContent);

PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDocument.DocumentPaginator, "test");
```

and myView contains this line of XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath,  Mode=OneWay, IsAsync=True}" />
```

Now if I print the FixedDocument, the image part is empty, as I'm assuming I'm assigning the view to the document before image is loaded.
How can I fix this issue, other than assigning IsAsync=False?

Comment: Download the image asynchronously yourself programmatically and bind without `IsAsync`.